# Mongodb updates always first doc in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to update one field in a document inside array. The problem is that it always updates the first element in array. I found out the problematic line (if I exclude it from the query updates work as expected).

```
        var query = {
            '_id':              documentId,
            'projectId':        { $in: userProjectIds }, // this line is causing problems, if I exclude it from the query, update works as expected
            'comments.id':      id
        };

        var update = {
            $set:   {
                'comments.$.content':      content
            }
        };
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

**EDIT:** It is a bug in mongoose.js 3.6.x series, it is fixed in 3.8.x (tested on 3.8.3). Thank you all for your answers, which helped me to pinpoint the bug.

Comment: So it updates all elements in an array without the functionality: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243 ?

Comment: I can't comment (due to the reputation).
But I don't understand why do use use this line causing problem?
`'_id': documentId,` select one document.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand how does this apply to my problem.  The object that I want to update is a comment inside array called comments. The first two lines of query (_id and projectId) are just there to select the parent object which contains the comments array. 'comments.id' is my only query against the array. The problem is that 'comments.id' just gets ignored and it updates the first comment in the parent object, what I want is to update the specific comment which matches the 'comments.id': id query.

Comment: No, I want to update one specific element, but somehow the query 'comments.id': id gets ignored (if I also have the projectId: { $in: userProjectIds }, which is just to select the parent object) and updates just the first element in array instead of the one matching the query 'comments.id': id.

Comment: oups sorry, it is my fault. Wait I am modifying my answer ;)

Comment: And you are doubly sure that it is updating comments that are not supposed to be updated? Hmm I can see no logical reasoning for this

Comment: Yes I am sure I spent a day debugging code. And yes if I remove the 'projectId': $in... part it updates the appropriate comment.

Comment: I need to check if the user has permission to modify the document, knowing the document id is not enough. That is the reason for query 'projectId': { $in: userProjectIds }

Comment: So strange.. I am sorry, I really don't know. Give us more about your code, and what contain exacly variables and your database. (because I tried with the mongo try it out, and it works)

Comment: Thank you, yes it works with mongo shell, but I have no idea why it does not work using mongoose & node.js... I'll investigate further.

Comment: Can you update your question to include your schema definitions and sample docs that reproduce the problem?